# Geting the encoding of an string that has \ values

Tags: python, string, encode, decoding

I have the following string that I am receiving via a python server. Do not have access to that server.

> \xa1\x823\xc2\xd5\x823\xc2\xff\x823\xc2\x12\x833\xc2\x1b\x833\xc2\x16\x833\xc2\x1e\x833\xc2 \x833\xc2\x0e\x833\xc2\x03\x833\xc2\x01\x833\xc2\x10\x833\xc2\'\x833\xc2\x17\x833\xc2\x00\x833\xc2\x11\x833\xc2$\x833\xc2$\x833\xc2\x1f\x833\xc2\x02\x833\xc2\xc0\x823\xc2\x94\x823\xc2\x91\x823\xc2\x7f\x823\xc2a\x823\xc2R\x823\xc2N\x823\xc2e\x823\xc2+\x823\xc2\xd3\x813\xc2\xee\x813\xc2\xe9\x813\xc2\xdf\x813\xc2\xfb\x813\xc2(\x823\xc25\x823\xc2\x17\x823\xc2\x1c\x823\xc2;\x823\xc2\xa2\x823\xc2\xe5\x823\xc2\xc2\x823\xc2\xbc\x823\xc2\x9b\x823\xc2\x13\x823\xc2\xbd\x813\xc2\xc0\x813\xc2\xc5\x813\xc2\xf2\x813\xc2(\x823\xc27\x823\xc2;\x823\xc2.\x823\xc2,\x823\xc20\x823\xc2\x11\x823\xc2\x0b\x823\xc2\xdf\x813\xc2\xb0\x813\xc2\xa2\x813\xc2\x7f\x813\xc2v\x813\xc2y\x813\xc2l\x813\xc2m\x813\xc2z\x813\xc2\x8c\x813\xc2\x89\x813\xc2w\x813\xc2Y\x813\xc2Y\x813\xc2c\x813\xc2e\x813\xc2Z\x813\xc2\x10\x813\xc2\xd2\x803\xc2\x8c\x803\xc2G\x803\xc2)\x803\xc2-\x803\xc2\x19\x803\xc2\xef\x7f3\xc2\xc9\x7f3\xc2\xc9\x7f3\xc2\xc8\x7f^C}3\xc2\xe7}3\xc2\xdd}3\xc2\xbc}3\xc2\xa9}3\xc2\xb7}3\xc2\xc1}3\xc2\xb0}3\xc2\x95}3\xc2\x9f}3\xc2\xd8}3\xc2\x05~3\xc2\x12~3\xc2\x15~3\xc2\r~3\xc2\x15~3\xc23~3\xc2/~3\xc2\x1d~3\xc2\x17~3\xc2\x15~3\xc2\x1d~3\xc2\x1e~3\xc2\x1a~3\xc2\x1f~3\xc2E~3\xc2W~3\xc2C~3\xc2o~3\xc2g~3\xc2p~3\xc2\xa3~3\xc2\x9b~3\xc2\x9e~3\xc2\x9e~3\xc2\xce~3\xc2\xe5~3\xc2\xe0~3\xc2\xd2~3\xc2\xc6~3\xc2\xc6~3\xc2\xc1~3\xc2\xca~3\xc2\xd6~3\xc2\xce~3\xc2\xa4~3\xc2\xad~3\xc2\xe1~3\xc2\xf8~3\xc2\xf8~3\xc2\x11\x7f3\xc2;\x7f3\xc2)\x7f3\xc2\xe6~3\xc2\xc4~3\xc2\xcc~3\xc2\xcd~3\xc2\xca~3\xc2\xc4~3\xc2\xbf~3\xc2\xcc~3\xc2\xc8~3\xc2\xc8~3\xc2\xd3~3\xc2\xd5~3\xc2\xa2~3\xc2L~3\xc2\x1c~3\xc2\x11~3\xc2\x14~3\xc2\x0e~3\xc2\x01~3\xc2\xf2}3\xc2\xf8}3\xc2\x05~3\xc2\xe3}3\xc2\xb0}3\xc2\x9c}3\xc2\x9e}3\xc2\x90}3\xc2\xcc}3\xc2\x1b~3\xc2\x05~3\xc2\xfa}3\xc2\x06~3\xc2\xf7}3\xc2\xf6}3\xc2\x15~3\xc2\x1f~3\xc2\x1b~3\xc2#~3\xc23~3\xc2H~3\xc2o~3\xc2\x89~3\xc2\x89~3\xc2\x94~3\xc2\x97~3\xc2\x84~3\xc2m~3\xc2\x8d~3\xc2\xdf~3\xc2\x0e\x7f3\xc2\x10\x7f3\xc27\x7f3\xc2]\x7f3\xc2i\x7f3\xc2e\x7f3\xc2[\x7f3\xc2k\x7f3\xc2x\x7f3\xc2\x89\x7f3\xc2\x9b\x7f3\xc2\xae\x7f3\xc2\xbd\x7f3\xc2\xb2\x7f3\xc2\xa4\x7f3\xc2\xba\x7f3\xc2\xce\x7f3\xc2\xd1\x7f3\xc2\xd0\x7f3\xc2\xc7\x7f3\xc2\xaa\x7f3\xc2m\x7f3\xc25\x7f3\xc2\x1e\x7f3\xc2\x1f\x7f3\xc2\x1b\x7f3\xc2\x1e\x7f3\xc2\r\x7f3\xc2\xed~3\xc2\xe3~3\xc2\xdd~3\xc2\xe6~3\xc2\x15\x7f3\xc2:\x7f3\xc29\x7f3\xc2B\x7f3\xc2N\x7f3\xc21\x7f3\xc2\x11\x7f3\xc2\x13\x7f3\xc2:\x7f3\xc2k\x7f3\xc2v\x7f3\xc2u\x7f3\xc2\x89\x7f3\xc2\x9f\x7f3\xc2\xa7\x7f3\xc2\xbe\x7f3\xc2\xd1\x7f3\xc2\xec\x7f3\xc2\n\x803\xc2\t\x803\xc2\x1f\x803\xc2Y\x803\xc2{\x803\xc2t\x803\xc2p\x803\xc2i\x803\xc2

In reality, this should be floating point number after decoding.

How can I decode it? How to know the encoding of the string? Preferably using python !!

I tried `chardet` , `decode('utf8')` and what not !! Any help is appreciated.

After trying this >

```
c=a.decode('utf-16-be', errors='ignore').encode('ascii')
```

Got this >

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
>   0-199: ordinal not in range(128)

after trying this >>>

```
c=a.decode('utf-16-le').encode('ascii')
```

Got this >>>>

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_16_le.py", line 16, in decode
>   return codecs.utf_16_le_decode(input, errors, True)
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0x33 in position
>   470: truncated data

Comment: maybe this helps: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624129/python-2-7-convert-utf8-string-to-ascii

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 2.7, convert utf8 string to ascii](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624129/python-2-7-convert-utf8-string-to-ascii)

Comment: None of them worked.

After trying this >
`c=a.decode('utf-16-be', errors='ignore').encode('ascii')`

Got this >

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-199: ordinal not in range(128)`

after trying this >>>

c=a.decode('utf-16-le').encode('ascii')

Got this >>>>

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_16_le.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_16_le_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0x33 in position 470: truncated data

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this data has been packed using the Python's [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module.
I'm not sure what the first two characters in the string represent, they aren't floats but could be `char`s or `short ints`.  The remainder of the string comprises of floats.

Ignoring the first two characters for now, we get:

`struct.unpack('!143f', s2[2:]) # s2 is the example string from the question
(9.037722037419371e-08, 9.038631532121144e-08, 9.036266845896535e-08, 9.071190731901879e-08, 9.06009489654025e-08, 9.058094008196349e-08, 9.058094008196349e-08, 9.058457806077058e-08, 9.063005279585923e-08, 9.067370854154433e-08, 9.071736428722943e-08, 9.071190731901879e-08, 9.064278572168405e-08, 9.063005279585923e-08, 9.062277683824504e-08, 9.059003502898122e-08, 9.058821603957767e-08, 9.057912109255994e-08, 9.057366412434931e-08, 9.054456029389257e-08, 9.051727545283939e-08, 9.05099994952252e-08, 9.04863526329791e-08, 9.046270577073301e-08, 9.04463348661011e-08, 9.04663437495401e-08, 9.050090454820747e-08, 9.054274130448903e-08, 9.050090454820747e-08, 9.052273242105002e-08, 9.062277683824504e-08, 9.061368189122732e-08, 9.067916550975497e-08, 9.07519250858968e-08, 9.073009721305425e-08, 9.071918327663298e-08, 9.06882604567727e-08, 9.066097561571951e-08, 9.071372630842234e-08, 9.071190731901879e-08, 9.069735540379043e-08, 9.071918327663298e-08, 9.071918327663298e-08, 9.071918327663298e-08, 9.075738205410744e-08, 9.076283902231808e-08, 9.072645923424716e-08, 9.074101114947553e-08, 9.070281237200106e-08, 9.069189843557979e-08, 9.069371742498333e-08, 9.066825157333369e-08, 9.062277683824504e-08, 9.060276795480604e-08, 9.063732875347341e-08, 9.06409667322805e-08, 9.068644146736915e-08, 9.074646811768616e-08, 9.072645923424716e-08, 9.073009721305425e-08, 9.074464912828262e-08, 9.06882604567727e-08, 9.068644146736915e-08, 9.074283013887907e-08, 9.075010609649325e-08, 9.070463136140461e-08, 9.069189843557979e-08, 9.075920104351098e-08, 9.079012386337126e-08, 9.078830487396772e-08, 9.034265957552634e-08, 9.036630643777244e-08, 9.038813431061499e-08, 9.04245140986859e-08, 9.051910154767029e-08, 9.056457628275894e-08, 9.056639527216248e-08, 9.061550798605822e-08, 9.071737139265679e-08, 9.07337422972887e-08, 9.077557905357025e-08, 9.042452120411326e-08, 9.040087434186717e-08, 9.037540849021752e-08, 9.03626755643927e-08, 9.039541737365653e-08, 9.046453897099127e-08, 9.043907311934163e-08, 9.042634019351681e-08, 9.046453897099127e-08, 9.050455673786928e-08, 9.052456562130828e-08, 9.050637572727283e-08, 9.046090099218418e-08, 9.041542625709553e-08, 9.036449455379625e-08, 9.080286389462344e-08, 9.034448567035724e-08, 9.077376006416671e-08, 9.070827644563906e-08, 9.066825867876105e-08, 9.068826756220005e-08, 9.070100048802487e-08, 9.065916373174332e-08, 9.065552575293623e-08, 9.073919926549934e-08, 9.038268444783171e-08, 9.039359838425298e-08, 9.044453008755227e-08, 9.059004923983593e-08, 9.06518948795565e-08, 9.06682657841884e-08, 9.079195706362952e-08, 9.044089921417253e-08, 9.044089921417253e-08, 9.042089033073353e-08, 9.041361437311934e-08, 9.041725235192644e-08, 9.039360548968034e-08, 9.042816628834771e-08, 9.048091698105054e-08, 9.053146499127251e-08, -75.2074203491211, -71.7074203491211, -61.10371017456055, -55.85371017456055, -58.35371017456055, -87.2074203491211, -102.7074203491211, -103.7074203491211, -107.2074203491211, -118.2074203491211, -114.7074203491211, -111.2074203491211, -105.7074203491211, -74.7074203491211, -58.10371017456055, -55.35371017456055, -58.55054473876953, 1.054752845871448e+18, 1005890699264.0, 6.59220528669655e+16, -7.216911831845169e-31)`

Treating the first two characters as `char`s:

`struct.unpack('!2c', s2[:2])
('5', 'g')`

As `short int`s:

`struct.unpack('!h', s2[:2])
(13671,)`

You can unpack the whole string at once by combining the formats:

`>>> struct.unpack('!h143f', s2)`

The format string consists of three parts:

- `!` indicates that we are using network (big-endian) byte order.
- `h` indicates the first 2 bytes are a `short` (the size of a `short int` is 2); if the first two bytes where `char`s (size 1) we would use `2c` instead of `h`.
- `143f` indicates that there follows 143 floats (the size of afloat is 4)

Added together, the sizes equal the length of the input string:

    `2 + (143 *4) == len(s2) == 574
    True`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. This is very helpful.

But The number should be `-44.something` . Also the stream I am getting has different sizes of strings...where all of them should have a value of `-44.something`.

The scenario is ...I am using one software to send values via UDP server, when I receive it via that same software I can clearly get the value. But I am trying to see it without that software.